# PL SQL Pivot: use different aggregates

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I want to pivot sum(sales) per country as below. But the price column should be an average per shop. So, I would love to have this result:

Desired Result:

| shop | avg_price | US | CN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 6 | 100 | 10 |
| 3 | 5 | 60 | 10 |

Current Result:

| shop | price | US | CN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | null | 5 |
| 2 | 7 | 100 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 | 60 | 10 |

I could skip price within the pivot part and simply rejoin it later on. However, I believe there is a smarter option. Can you help me out?

Query (so far)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
         SELECT 'US' AS country, 2 AS shop, 50 AS sales, 5 AS price
           FROM dual
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CN' AS country, 2 AS shop, 5 AS sales, 7 AS price
           FROM dual
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'US' AS country, 3 AS shop, 50 AS sales, 5 AS price
           FROM dual
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CN' AS country, 3 AS shop, 5 AS sales, 5 AS price
           FROM dual
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'US' AS country, 2 AS shop, 50 AS sales, 5 AS price
           FROM dual
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CN' AS country, 2 AS shop, 5 AS sales, 5 AS price
           FROM dual
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'US' AS country, 3 AS shop, 10 AS sales, 5 AS price
           FROM dual
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'CN' AS country, 3 AS shop, 5 AS sales, 5 AS price
           FROM dual
       )
 PIVOT ( SUM(sales) FOR country IN ( 'US','CN' )
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by `shop` while adding double-quoted aliases for each pivoted columns such as

```
SELECT shop, AVG(price) AS avg_price, SUM("US") AS us, SUM("CN") AS cn
  FROM t
 PIVOT ( SUM(sales) for country in ( 'US' AS "US",'CN' AS "CN" ) )
 GROUP BY shop
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c9ee89dbea293873252a3d0ce25889cb)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I guess, the double-quoted alias made the difference (I must have tried this version without them before...)